# rxjs5 - no WebSocket constructor can be found

Tags: typescript, commonjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to do something basic, but it's completely eluding me. I'm trying to create an `Observable` from `rxjx/observable/dom/webSocket` in [RxJS5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs), but I'm not using typescript, or es6 modules... just plain 'ole good commonJS.  I've managed to patch the Observable properly according to the docs, but whenever I try to pass in the string expected for the subject, I get the error:

`no WebSocket constructor can be found`, [[source]](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fd0823b99db92d1e214052ad506904b0d744d494/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L52-L68).

I haven't had time to dig into TypeScript yet, but from what I can tell, I've satisfied the conditions of the constructor, and I've also taken a look at the test spec, and [they use the function in the same way](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fd0823b99db92d1e214052ad506904b0d744d494/spec/observables/dom/webSocket-spec.ts#L34) `Observable.webSocket('ws://host:port');` I'm trying to, but I *still* get an error.

I've tried:

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
require('rxjs/Rx.dom').webSocketSubject; //also tried just using `.webSocket`

var source = Rx.Observable.webSocket('ws://localhost:53311');

source.subscribe();
```

I've also tried passing an object to `Rx.Observable.webSocket`:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://host:port'
});
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to use the `webSocket` Observable that's [available via rxjs5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/observable/dom/webSocket.ts), when consuming from commonJS? (node v5.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't about TypeScript, you may need provide constructor to websocket to WebSocketSubject.

In test case, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fd0823b99db92d1e214052ad506904b0d744d494/spec/observables/dom/webSocket-spec.ts#L14 specifies it in root to globally override websocket, while it's also possible to provide it as config object like

```
var ws = require('websocket');

socket = new WebSocketSubject({
  url: 'ws://....',
  WebSocketCtor: ws.w3cwebsocket
});
```

Even required in TypeScript or ES15 RxJS module as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I know because I wrote the code in RxJS 5. ;)  ... If you're running in an environment that doesn't have a window.WebSocket or global.WebSocket, like Node.js, it will not automatically find one, which means you'll need to provide one in the manner described above.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  @BenLesh I'm doing some stuff in the main electron process, which is why I'm running into this. If you'd like I will write up some documentation of client usage from node and submit a PR.