# rxjs5 - WebSocketSubject is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, rxjs, rxjs5

So I am trying to utilize rxjs's **Observable.webSocket** in a node.js environment. I saw from the docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855367/rxjs5-no-websocket-constructor-can-be-found) stack overflow post that it is required that I provide my own version of websocket. The problem I'm coming across is that both of the examples provided indicate a **WebSocketSubject**, but they do not mention where this comes from.

```
const ws = require('nodejs-websocket');
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const WebSocketSubject = require('rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject');

socket = new WebSocketSubject({url: 'ws://....', WebSocketCtor: ws.w3cwebsocket});

const marketSocket$ = Rx.Observable.webSocket('ws://....');
```

This was my attempt at retrieving the necessary WebSocketSubject, but I just get an error telling me that "WebSocketSubject is not a constructor". Is there something painfully obvious I'm missing? If you could share a working solution providing a valid websocket constructor(with all needed references provided) along with an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong that would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `require` will return the module that contains the `WebSocketSubject`, so your require call should look like this:

```js
const WebSocketSubject = require('rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject').WebSocketSubject;
```

Or like this:

```js
const { WebSocketSubject } = require('rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject');
```

Comment: Indeed. The RxJS APIs differ with established conventions as shown.

Comment: Thanks @cartant. That solves that issue, but now I seem to run into the same error as the stack overflow question I referenced above: ''no WebSocket constructor can be found''. For some reason I can't satisfy the requirement of providing a valid constructor.

Comment: @kelibra The code in your snippet does not appear to be appropriate for the [`nodejs-websocket` client API](https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket#wsconnecturl-options-callback). Perhaps you should try [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws), instead - it has plenty of GitHub stars.